# Real Analysis : $x^n = a$ has only one solution.

Tags: real-analysis, roots

I have a question regarding the following exercises.

(1)
Let $n \in \mathbb {N}$. For all $a \in \mathbb {R}$ with $a \geq 0$ there exists $x \in \mathbb {R}$  with $x \geq 0$ such that $x^n = a$.

(2) The equation $x^n = a$ has just one solution for $x \geq 0$. That solution is called $n$-th root of $a$.

These two problems seem intuitive. Especially the second one since to me it seems that there is only some small step required to get me the right result / proof. However, Taking the $n$-th root obviously is not the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative approach for (2). Suppose $x^n=y^n=a$ where $x,y\geq 0$ and $x\neq y$. Since
$$0=x^n-y^n=(x-y)\times\sum_{k=0}^nx^ky^{n-k},$$
and $x-y\neq0$, we must have $\sum_{k=0}^nx^ky^{n-k}=0$. But every term of this sum is nonnegative, and $x,y$ are different so the first and last terms can't both be $0$, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you! I've seen this formula in our script but didn't know these were related to eachother. Could the same thing be done with (1)?

Comment: @23408924 Not easily, since (1) is essentially the intermediate value theorem. You can perhaps use this formula to argue that if you have an approximation $x$ then you can choose a nearby $y$ such that the difference $y^n-x^n$ is between $a-x^n$ and $(a-x^n)/2$, then define a sequence of approximations and take a limit, but that sounds awkward to do rigorously..

Comment: I see, That does sound quite difficult and since we haven't covered limits yet, probably not what they're looking for. It's weird since I am familiar with these concepts but can only apply them once they've talked about it

Comment: @23408924 I don't see how it's possible to do (1) without some form of limits, since it is not true in $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: The solution for (2) seems exactly what i needed, since the formula you posted came up in the same exercise. Just that (1) seems somewhat trivial just that I'cant prove it with just the propositions in my script it seems.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use continuity of the function $f(x):=x^n$.

> $f(0)\le a$ and $f(\max(a,1))\ge a$ so by the intermediate value theorem there must be an $x$ such that $f(x)=a$.

2. $f(x)$ is a strictly growing function.

> $x>y\implies x^n>y^n$. So $x^n=b^n=a\implies x=y$.

---

Alternatively, for 1. we can show that the subset $$A:=\{x\in\mathbb R:x^n<a\},B=\mathbb R\setminus A$$ defines a Dedekind cut.

- $A\ne \emptyset$ and $A,B$ partition $\mathbb R$.
- $x^n<a\land y^n\ge a\implies x^n<y^n\implies x<y$, by monotonicity.
- if $y^n\ge a$, $x:=\min_{y\in\mathbb R}(y)\in B$ because $x^n\ge a$. (By monotonicity, infimum and power commute.)

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes a lot of sense. However, since we haven't covered the intermediate value theorem yet, (I only know it from the last term) I'm pretty sure they would not accept this.

Comment: @23408924: have you learnt the definition of reals by Dedekind cuts, then ?

Comment: Yes that sounds familiar.

Comment: @23408924: I find it weird that you accepted an answer that does not address item 1. at all. You made me waste my time.

Comment: Sorry! I wasn't done checking everything on here. My bad! Thank you very much for your solution. I didn't mean to waste your time. I wish I could accept 2 answers, since you proved part 1.

Answer (score 1):

Too trivial?

Uniqueness of solution.

1)$a>0;$

Assume that $x^n =y^n=a.$ Then $x, y >0.$

$(x/y)^n=1$ $\Rightarrow x/y=1;$ $x=y;$

2)$a=0;$

Implies $x=y=0.$

Appended:

$ b:=x/y =1$ is the only real number $b>0$ that satisfies

$b^n=1;$

1)Assume $b>1$.

Then $b^2>b>1$. Continuing inductively

we get  $b^n>1;$

2)Assume $b<1;$

Similarly we get  $b^n<1;$

3)$b=1$ satisfies $b^n=1,$ and

we are done.

Comment: This assumes the result holds for $a=1$.

Comment: Especially Lime. Do not understand. Any $a>0.$ $x^n/y^n=a/a=1$. Do I miss something. Please elaborate.

Comment: Yes, but how do you know that $(x/y)^n=1$ implies $x/y=1$? That assumes there is a unique solution to $z^n=1$, which is a special case of what you're trying to prove.

Comment: Consider this: Assume $x/y=:b >1$. Then $b^2>b>1,$ inductive : $b^n >1$. Similarly for $b<1. $ Hence $b=1.$ Your thoughts ?

Comment: Yes, that works and adding it into your answer would make it complete.

Comment: Hopefully better now. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @PeterSzilas Thanks for your answer! I understand it now.

Comment: @23408924. A  pleasure.